# How can we create a proper vector SVG file from HTML canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

#### What I am trying to achieve:

Generate an SVG file from html canvas using javascript.

#### What I have tried:

1. I am generating the image I need using HTML canvas using canvas's CanvasRenderingContext2D and createCanvas().
2. Writing it to an svg file using canvas's toBuffer() and node's writeFileSync() functions.

#### The problem:

The generated file is not an actual vector image, but a flattened image in svg format.

**This does not allow design softwares to modify the svg.**

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800pt" height="800pt" viewBox="0 0 800 800" version="1.1">
<defs>
<image id="image47" width="800" height="800" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA

//...

</defs>
<g id="surface36">
<use xlink:href="#image47"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to generate an actual vector (that can be edited in design softwares) from the HTML canvas using any other approach / third party libraries?

Comment: I was using `d3` to create svg and `defs` which will give me more fancy icons in svg.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that the generated svg is actually a flattened image and not an actual dynamic vector.

Comment: canvas is a raster technology, SVG is a vector technology. Going from raster to vector is not straightforward. Generate the image you need using SVG DOM rather than canvas.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up implementing the images in SVG using SVG.js instead. It took more work but is a more sustainable solution I feel.